# fadein div when changing display -> inline with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam working on a project where i have a "side pop up", i want to have it set to display: none in css on start to make sure it dosnt "blink" as it does when using jquerys "hide()". the question is: 
 - How do i make the div fadein when setting the display property to "inline" through jquery?

my code ish(only made for demonstration purpose):
https://jsfiddle.net/dzm50k39/

ive tried using

```
  $(".popupContent").fadeIn().css("display", "inline");
```

this only fades the buttons in tho. 

Any suggestions on how to do this with jquery or css?

if possible i'd like to not fadein but slide up from the bottom.

Comment: fadeIn itself sets display

Comment: You can do this with pure css if you don't insist on the click but are ok with just hovering the side pop up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do it in the following way:

keep your `display:none` on in the css and the use the following:

```
$(".popupContent").css("display", "inline").hide().fadeIn();  // ends as an inline object
```

If you are wanting to change it to inline after the fade in, then you need to do this in the callback function:

```
$(".popupContent").fadeIn(function() {
   $(this).css("display", "inline")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by transition Property to make fade-in or fade-out

```
$(".popupContent").css("display", "inline");
```

CSS:

```
.popupContent
{
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Hope it Helps

Comment: no probs: try this  $(".popupContent).css({
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline-block'     
    }).animate({opacity:1},600);

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced your .css items with .fadein see the [jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/7xdkfeva/)

example:

```
$(".popupContent").fadeIn(1000);
```